# Xcode How to stop a timer Label with an if statement when a UITextField has the same text as a UILabel

Tags: xcode, if-statement, timer, uitextfield, uilabel

I have been trying to do this on an app for a long time but I cannot get it to work, please could someone help me and post some code on how I would do it. What I need to happen is when the text in the UITextField equal the UILabel. Thanks

h. viewcontroller

```
@interface AlphabetSceneViewController : UIViewController {

UILabel *stopWatchLabel;
NSTimer *stopWatchTimer;
NSDate *startDate;

IBOutlet UILabel *wordToType;
IBOutlet UITextField *wordTyped;
```

and the m. view controller

```
    - (void)updateTimer
{
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss.SSS"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    stopWatchLabel.text = timeString;
}

- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender {
    startDate = [NSDate date];

    stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender {    

    [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    stopWatchTimer = nil;
    [self updateTimer];

    if ([wordToType.text isEqualToString:@"stop"]) {

    }

}
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain what calls your two IBAction methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, I'll put up the code for anyone that wanted to know. It's only code for the .m file and the alert view is just a bit of extra code on the end to make it show an alert when with the time that the user had when the timer stops.

```
- (IBAction)stopTimer:(id)sender {

    if([wordTyped.text isEqualToString:wordToType.text]){

        [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
        stopWatchTimer = nil;
        [self updateTimer];


        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Nice Work" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Good Job! You're time to type the alphabet was %@. Let's see if you can do better...", stopWatchLabel.text]
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Main Menu" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];
    }
}
```